# Gridview with custom adapter not working and adapter getView is not run in Android

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am developing an Android app using Android Studio. In my app I need to work with grid view because my app includes some features something like Facebook newfeeds. I am using volley to request data from server.

I created an Custom Array Adapter for grid view. But the problem is nothing is bind to the grid view even if the volley request is success and contains so many items. I am %100 sure volley and server side working correctly. But nothing is bind to grid view. Below is my code.

My custom adapter class

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{
    private ArrayList<Item> values;
    private Context context;

    static class ViewHolder{
        public ImageView imageViewItemImg;
        public TextView tvItemName;
        public TextView tvItemPrice;
        public TextView tvItemLikeCount;
    }

    public ItemListAdapter(Context contextParam,ArrayList<Item> valuesParam)
    {
        super(contextParam,-1,valuesParam);
        this.context = contextParam;
        this.values = valuesParam;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(rowView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_item_view,null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.imageViewItemImg = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_list_view_item_image);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder  = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }
        rowView.setId(values.get(position).getId());
        if(values.get(position).getMediumImageUrl()!=null && values.get(position).getMediumImageUrl().isEmpty()==false)
        {
            Picasso.with(context).load(values.get(0).getMediumImageUrl()).into(viewHolder.imageViewItemImg);
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

My fragment with grid view

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 .
 .
 .
 listItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
 adapter = new ItemListAdapter(getActivity(),listItems);
 .
 .
 .
 .
 updateItemList();
 return view;
}

public void updateItemList()
{

.
.
.

JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new JSONObject(paramString), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try{
                        String status = response.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.api_status));
                        if(status.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.api_status_success)))
                        {
                            //can be asked to login again
                            JSONArray items = response.getJSONArray("items");
                            ArrayList<Item> newItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
                            if(items.length()>0)
                            {
                                for(int i=0;i<items.length();i++)
                                {
                                    Item item = new Item();
                                    item.setMediumImageUrl(items.getString(i));
                                    newItems.add(item);
                                }
                            }

                            if(newItems.size()>0)
                            {
                                listItems.addAll(newItems);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            showMessageDialog("Server error encountered");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        showMessageDialog("An error encountered");
                    }
                    page++;
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    showMessageDialog(error.getMessage());
                }
            });
            VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);

.
.
.
}
```

Layout file for fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Item List"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gv_item_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></GridView> </LinearLayout>
```

This is the row or item layout for grid view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_list_view_item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Why is getView function is never run and not returning anything?

Comment: Is that your complete adapter code.

Comment: Yes for now.Cause I am testing it first.

Comment: `@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return values.size();
    }`

try adding this to your adapter.

Comment: No it is not working. Even the getView is not run.

Comment: `@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return values.size();
    }
 @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }`

try adding this to your adapter.

Comment: try to add all these to adapter

Comment: I tried. It is not working as well. What is wrong ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105854/discussion-between-dhina-and-wai-yan-hein).

Comment: I solved the error. I forgot to call griview.setAdapter(adapter) . Thanks u all.

Comment: Yes i have said the same too in the answer

Answer (score 0):

This line is never called, that is why, so fix it

```
if(newItems.size()>0) {
    listItems.addAll(newItems);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

i mean the condition is never met. actually debug it.

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter = new ItemListAdapter(getActivity(),listItems);
```

you are doing this in Oncreateview where listitems is null

```
if(newItems.size()>0){ 
  listItems.addAll(newItems); 
  adapter = new ItemListAdapter(getActivity(),listItems); 
  griview.setAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

Comment: I am updating it when volley request is success.